# Reviewers want me to cite their barely related papers

Tags: citations, journals, peer-review, paper-submission

I recently sent a paper to a journal which has now been reviewed by 2 reviewers. Both of them have some good points that I should change. However, both reviewers also suggest to include specific papers to "enhance" my paper.

However: These papers are barely related to my paper.

- In case of reviewer 1 the whole research group of the papers suggested by this reviewer is identical for each paper.
- In case of reviewer 2 five papers have been suggested. Even though different authors are listed two identical authors appear on each of these papers. Sometimes as a first author, sometimes not. But it seems obvious to me that one of these two authors must be reviewer 2.

I don't know how to deal with that. Should I write the editor? Should I ignore their suggestions? Should I include at least one of these references to make them happy? Their general opinion about our paper was good.

Comment: Note that the answers to the marked duplicate address  (1) what to do when the suggested papers _are_ relevant, **and** (2) what to do when the suggested papers are _not_ relevant.